# ContactKey / SubscriberKey

Tags: marketing-cloud

Some talking about ContactKeys some about SubscriberKeys are this two different things? If yes, whats the differences? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Key is a unique identifier that binds your contact to the data model in Contact Builder. It is used mainly in Journey Builder and other modules (Except EmailStudio)

SubscriberKey is an EmailStudio attribute that creates a primary relationship with your email studio audience.

Contacts can therefore have both a Contact Key and Subscriber Key.

Best Practice is to use the same identifier for both.

The Official Documentation has a good piece on it that can be found in [Contact Builder Best Practices](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/contact_builder_best_practices/) . I would recommend reading the whole bit, but the areas of particular interest to this questions are:

- Understand the Difference Between All Subscribers and All Contacts Lists
- Understand the Differences Between Contact ID and Subscriber ID versus Contact Key and Subscriber Key